# FLASK - Could not build url for endpoint in blueprint with parameter

Tags: python, flask

I have a modular app with blueprint structure. I registered the blueprints and they are working fine. I am having problems with the url_for with parameters:

**werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'confirm_email' with values ['token']**

here is my the endpoint in **home.py**

```
@home.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():

    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    print(form, file=sys.stderr)
    print(form.email, file=sys.stderr)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        u = User(
            email = form.email.data,
            password = form.password.data
        )
        email_ddbb = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        # we register the user
        if email_ddbb is None:
            # Now we'll send the email confirmation link
            subject = "Confirm your email"
            token = ts.dumps(u.email, salt='email-confirm-key')
            print(url_for('user.activate',token=token,_external=True))
            confirm_url = url_for('user.activate',token=token,_external=True)
            html = render_template('mail/activate.html', confirm_url=confirm_url)
            # we send the email from utils.py
            send_email(u.email, subject, html)
            db.session.add(u)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Thanks for registering, please check your inbox')
            return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
        else:
            flash('Email already in use')
            return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
        #TODO MUST BE UNIQUE
    else:
        flash('Please enter a valid email address')
        return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
```

and here is the other endpoint in **user.py**

```
@user.route('/confirm/<token>')
def activate(token):
    try:
        email = ts.loads(token, salt="email-confirm-key", max_age=86400)
    except:
        abort(404)
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
    user.verified = True
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
```

Comment: If i commit the user before the error to the database and then I visit **manually** the printed url (ie http://127.0.0.1:5000/confirm/ImFzZGZAYXNkZi5jb20i.C-xnqg.4Hb4DU4b-Txiy3v7yhNdW6-beUE) it works

Comment: app.url_map confirms the endpoint, still no clue <Rule '/confirm/<token>' (HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS) -> user.activate>,

Answer (score 0):

Okey, the problem was not in there but in the mailing:

```
def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    msg = Message(app.config['MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + subject,
                      sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = ''
    token = ts.dumps(to, salt='email-confirm-key')

    confirm_url = url_for(
        'confirm_email', <-- should be user.activate 
        token=token,
        _external=True)

    msg.html = render_template(
            'activate.html',
            confirm_url=confirm_url)
    mail.send(msg)
```